# How to convert a CSV to xlxs file in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-excel

I am trying to convert a CSV to an xlxs file format because I have a code that is meant to read a an excel file, but ended up getting a CSV. Is there a way to convert a CSV file to an TEMP excel file and have it not destroyed until the reading process is done. I have tried using openpyxl but it ends up not working and throwing an error saying it's not a good zip file. I even tried converting the CSV to text and then storing it in a dictionary but it writing to excel using xlrd pakage did not work aswell. I was wondering if there is a way do it in a cc

Comment: CSV stands for comma separated values. It is a text file and can be read / written easily by text editors, python or excel.

What you are trying to achieve is not clear. Show your code and error messages.

Comment: `for r, row in enumerate(reader):
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Comment: @user3570849 provide your code in the question give sample input and expected output and also provide the error traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you open the file in text mode. Try this to open file

```
open('sample.csv', "rt", encoding="utf8")
```

or

```
open('sample.csv', "rt", encoding="ascii")
```

depending on the encoding of the file

Comment: Yeah in this line I had rb, I read the documentaion and found out that it needs to be r  `with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:`